# Check if Firebase User is null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm making a Flutter App and I want to check if the user is registered in the database when he logs in the app.

So basically if he's registered and he logs in with no errors, there will be a loading indicator and he will be redirected to the Homepage.

If he made an error (wrong email/password for example) he will get snackbar displaying the error.

The problem is that I couldn't find the right 'if statement' to check if the user is registered or not.

Here's my Login button :

`

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
                        var email = _emailController.text;

                        var password = _passwordController.text;

                        User? user =
                            (await _auth.login(email, password, context));

                        user != null
                            ? setState(() => loading = true)
                            : setState(() => loading = false);

                        print(loading);
                      }
                    },
                    child: loading
                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : Text('Connect'),
                  ),
```

`

And the login function :

```
Future login(String email, password, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email, password: password))
          .user!;

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, DiscoverPage.id);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      var message = '';
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'user-not-found':
          message = 'User not found';
      }
      print(error.code);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        CustomSnackBar(message, context),
      );
    }
  }
```

'loading' is initiated to false and when I print(loading) it always returns false, no matter if there's an error or not. The setState dont seem to work.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: so your problem is that you want the e.code for all possible FirebaseAuthException to cath them ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy No my problem is that I want to know what check operator I need to use in the setState to check if the user is successfully logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 try {
  User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password))
      .user!;
  if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, DiscoverPage.id);
  }
} on ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I actually used a try catch in my login function, and when the user correctly logs in, he's redirected to the Homepage.
The problem is that if he's made an error (wrong password for example), he's not redirected and the spinner keeps loading forever because the loading is now 'true' and I can't get it back to 'false'.

Comment: ok then I will edit it to forcefully check for auth state